# An error occurred while communicating with Topology Manager 'http://localhost:81/ttm201601'

Tags: publishing, topology-manager, publishtransaction

While Publishing we are getting the below error

> An error occurred while communicating with Topology Manager
>   'http://localhost:81/ttm201601'

When we re-publish multiple times, items are getting success.

Unable to find any logs which reflects the error in CMS and Publisher servers.

Any suggestions to resolve the above error.

Comment: What version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: We are using SDL Web 8.5

Comment: Have you checked/enabled TTM logging/exceptions in: ``<tridion-root>\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web\Logging.config`` to get more logging info?

Comment: What’s the architecture you’re working with? Single Cm, single Deployer/worker? Load balancing? Etc?  The more information you can share then the more relevant suggestions can be.

Comment: TopMan is deployed with your CM server. Based on the above error, it looks like you are having issues with incorrect services running on your scaled out architecture. As @Dylan..MarkSaunders pointed out, more information on your architecture will help provide streamlined answers

Comment: Also take a look at the following SDL article https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000005294

Comment: We have 2 CM and 2 Publishers and 2 Deployers and On F5 Loadbalancer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find nothing in the publisher logs or in the Topology logs about the failed transaction id or the id of the item you are publishing.

The problem is caused if the W3SVC service is not running.

This causes the local topology manager running on the publisher to stop and hence the error message

An error occurred while communicating with Topology Manager 'http://localhost:81/ttm201601'